# Conditional logic for all values with a prefix

Tags: sas

Suppose I have a list of variables with a common prefix. Is it possible to use If/then logic on all of those variables at once?

**Data** I have 3 columns:

```
data have;
  length column1-column2 $8 column3 8;
  input column1-column3;
  datalines;
CC A_var1 12
HH A_var2 212
CC A_var3 221
CC B_var1 66
HH B_var2 545
CC B_var3 454
;
```

```
* untested;
data  test;
  set source;
  if column1 = 'CC' then A: = .
run;
```

Comment: Where are the variables with prefix A? In another table?

Comment: For the first row > Column 1 = CC, Column 2 = A_var1, Column 3 = 12. For every occurrence of CC in column 1, I want every instance in column 2 with the prefix "A_" to equal blank.

Comment: Show the result you want after processing the data.  Do you want `column3` set to missing, or `column2` ?

Comment: Do you want to use the data in the HAVE dataset to generate the code in your example?  What are the names of the variables in the SOURCE dataset?  Please show examples of SOURCE and expected output of TEST for those values.

Comment: I updated the question/subject to reflect you want to check values, not variables.  It is just that the values happen to be variable names.

Comment: Thanks, for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:` modifier on the operator in the IF statement to do a truncated string comparison.

```
data want;
  set have;
  if column1='CC' and column2 =: 'A_' then column3=.;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    column1    column2    column3

 1       CC       A_var1         .
 2       HH       A_var2       212
 3       CC       A_var3         .
 4       CC       B_var1        66
 5       HH       B_var2       545
 6       CC       B_var3       454
```

Comment: Thanks, for your time.